# Increase performance of Symfony2 with angularJS application

Tags: multithreading, symfony, websocket, long-polling, ratchet

We have an application built in Symfony2 with AngularJS. The performance of the application is degrading with the increasing number of users.

Application web pages needed to be updated continuously; addition to this there are some modals, need to be updated. Currently I am relying on regular Ajax requests. To keep the page up to date I am sending 2 Ajax request in every 2 seconds. Whenever user pulls up a modal, app stops updating page, sends an Ajax request to get data for the modal and then continuously sends Ajax request in every 2 seconds to update that modal. once the user has closed the modal app resumes Ajax requests for page.

As this scenarios replicates to 100s of work stations; Server gets busy and Ajax request takes longer to complete. Usually Ajax request for modals takes around 1 second but once server gets busy request takes 2 to 3 seconds, which is significant delay for users.

After Googling for long, I have came across few solutions, but not sure which solution is the best as I cannot try and test each of them:

My first solution includes **long polling** keeping the regular Ajax requests to update the page and use long polling to update modal as they don't change frequently. Downside of this is long polling from first client will keep the server busy which will cause delay for other clients. In addition to delay, server will have hard time in detecting canceled/aborted long polling.

**Web sockets**
web sockets seems a good contender but Apache doesn't supports it. For this problem I can use Ratchet but IE-9 doesn't supports it by default. There are few polyfills for that; but requests are still handled in a queue. So the time saved by reusing connection will have no positive effect.

**Server send event**
We are already using it for another application. It can also reuse the connection but server will have hard time in detecting application close; besides this server will stay busy and may take longer to handle multiple clients connections.

**Multi threading**
PHP is now capable of running multiple threads. I can have a thread for every Ajax request but this set up will create large number of threads as PHP is not good at garbage collection, this can cause memory leak.

I am also considering combination of long polling and multi threading or server send event and multi threading.

Our environment has some restrictions such as

- We have to support all browsers but IE-9 is intended one.
- Workstations ranges from thin clients to PCs to virtual desktops.
- Number of users fluctuates during the day.
- Besides we are using Angular application is not actually a single page app.
- Application is up and running continuously on smart screens.
- We want to preload data for Modals, so users won't wait for modal to appear.

I believe I have look at every possible solution. Let me know if I have missed any.

Every suggestion is welcomed

Comment: If you've got hundreds of users, why not just add a server or two to take more load?

Comment: Alister Bulman; Good idea but I can't keep on adding more and more servers. Adding more servers is expensive and number of users accessing it can go up or down depending on the time of day. Adding more servers won't make application faster but it will increase the maintenance for us.

Answer (score 0):

Im no sure about where your problem is, but if u use ajax to constantly updating each 2s it can be u have many request in one time from one client, so ur server have hard time. I prefer use to not make request each 2s, but after respond (success or not) add another request with waiting time 2s, so u make chain of request, and have only one from one client. 
Next stuff is performance on ur server, because 1-3s responds time is big, is running on prod env, see profiler and see what take so long, maybe using twig, for json request etc...

Comment: sedziwoj: Ajax requests are already chained up. At any given time there is maximum 3 Ajax requests in pending state. I can squeeze all the requests into one but, server will take more time in processing and in putting all together.  Server takes long in responding on a busy day; I know what's the exact issue. Server expects synchronous  requests but Ajax is Asynchronous and from multiple clients.

Comment: So u dont have to many request, only server not handle it. 
If u make less request in one time, it not give much, because some will wait for end others request.
U can do constant one connection (like in Android) and if something change u get info, and make request reconnect, but i dont know if there r some libs for it and if it works on apache.
U can use nginx with php-fpm, it should give some boost in performance.
I think most help optimize time processing to make response, u can add cache, so not generate same content multiple time, and add time cache so u generate only each 1s new content.

Comment: sedziwoj: I am planning to go with Server send event as a solution. With this I can maintain a connection for longer period (i.e. default 30 sec). In theory it will reduce the burden on Server as application will process information once and send out to all connected clients.

Comment: i have seen few posts which have mentioned the draw back of using Server send events. Apache creates thread for every request and there's a limit to these threads. Although Apache documentation says we can have unlimited keep alive requests. - [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation).

Comment: Do u try cache this response? U can make cache generate on new data, so u always load from cache (if this data r not per user). U can make optimize how they r generate (optimize sql, caching remote data etc). It may be easier to do than keeping alive connections.

Comment: I don't think caching will work as script is generating new data every 2 seconds and that data need to be replicate to all clients.

Comment: But u generet one cache for all clients, so client count not make it take longer wait time.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds dumb but, if I am creating data only when I am sending it out and it's new every time then why I would cache it and for what.

Comment: Yes I have tried this bundle. I have even requested developer of that bundle to downgrade it and add support for IE. I also want to use WebSocket but it will require lot of changes to the application.